# What to use instead of onerror to show a default image

Tags: html

When you load a grid of images there is a chance that one or more images are not found. In those cases, I do not want to show a blank space or an ugly browser-default "Image Not Found"-icon. Instead, I want to show a default image or some kind of thumbnail.

One way to achieve this is to use the `onerror`-tag like this:

```
<img src="example.png" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='not- 
found.jpg';" alt="Some example image I expect to load!" />
```

When an error occurs, e.g the image resource is not found, the `onerror`-tag is executed and the `src` of the image is set to a default not-found image. `this.onerror=null` is to avoid an infinite loop in case the not-found image is also not found.

But this method seems to be [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#browser_compatibility).

Every Google result shows the `onerror`-method when I search on how to handle not-found images like this.

So, what would be the best way to show a default image when an image is not found?

I thought that `<picture>` worked like this, but it doesn't.

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="example.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="example.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
    <img alt="" src="not-found.jpg">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the GlobalEventHandler `onerror` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

> When a resource (such as an `<img>` or `<script>`) fails to load, an error
> event using interface Event is fired at the element that initiated the
> load, and the onerror() handler on the element is invoked. These error
> events do not bubble up to window, but can be handled with a
> EventTarget.addEventListener configured with useCapture set to true.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: the documentation was fixed. `onerror` is NOT deprecated.

---

There is a related issue on MDN: [img onerror is deprecated? #4014](https://github.com/mdn/sprints/issues/4014). OP speculated that it could be an error related to MDN and not an actual deprecation.

Personally: I really couldn't tell if it's one or the other. I subscribed to the issue but, for the time being, I'm going to use `onError` as always, with a comment to check this page.